# How to position the HERE maps infobubble, so it does not hide the marker

Tags: javascript, here-api

Here's a picture. The default infobubble covers the marker it belongs to (see the bottom right corner of the bubble):

[image]

This is [from their official example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/open-infobubble).

Is there an easy way to make the marker appear above the bubble, so the bubble does not hide it?

Currently, it's confusing, because it's not easy to see which marker the bubble belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my simple solution based on the other answer by Here support:

```
var xy = map.geoToScreen(coords);

var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(map.screenToGeo(xy.x, xy.y - 30), {
  content: 'content'
});

ui.addBubble(bubble);
```

coords is the marker coordinates, and it places the infowindow 30 pixel above the marker.

This works for me, because in my case the marker is always in the center of map.

Edit: it's not perfect, because if you zoom the map then the marker and bubble point to different places, so there should also be an event handler which updates the bubble position when zooming

Answer (score 2):

You can try this sample code:

```
// check if info bubble is visible, otherwise move the map center
            function checkInfoBubble(infoBubble){
                setTimeout(function() {
                      if(infoBubble && infoBubble.getState() == "open"){
                        var border = 50;
                        var objRect = infoBubble.getContentElement().parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                        var objStyleRight = Math.abs(parseInt(infoBubble.getContentElement().parentElement.style.right));
                        objStyleRight = objStyleRight ? objStyleRight : 0;

                        var mapRect = map.getElement().getBoundingClientRect();
                        var shiftX = 0;
                        var shiftY = 0;

                        // check, if infobubble isn't too far to up
                        if ((objRect.top-border)  < mapRect.top)  {
                            shiftY = (mapRect.top - (objRect.top-border));
                        }

                        // check, if infobubble isn't too far to the left
                        var objLeft = (objRect.left - objStyleRight);
                        if ((objLeft-border) < mapRect.left) {
                            shiftX = (mapRect.left - (objLeft-border));
                        } // check, if infobubble isn't too far to the right
                        else if ((objRect.right+border) > mapRect.right) {
                            shiftX = -(objRect.right - (mapRect.right-border));
                        }


                        if ((shiftX == 0) && (shiftY == 0)) {
                            return;
                        }

                        var currScreenCenter = map.geoToScreen(map.getCenter());
                        var newY = (currScreenCenter.y - shiftY);
                        var newX = (currScreenCenter.x - shiftX);

                         var newGeoCenter = map.screenToGeo(newX, newY);
                         map.setCenter(newGeoCenter, true); 
                    }


                 }, 20);
            }
```

Furthermore is shown here: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/show_info_on_hover

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a simple way to set the mark z-order compared to the infobubble, so the mark covers the bubble tail. Is this possible?  This would be the simplest. You solution also works, of course, I guess its main gist is using the geoToScreen and screenToGeo methods to calculate the position of the infobubble above the mark.